# Include variable in jsonpath for oc patch (openshift CLI operations)

Tags: openshift, jsonpath

In bash I am trying to use a variable in a jsonpath for an openshift `patch` cli command:

```
  OS_OBJECT='sample.k8s.io/element'
  VALUE='5'
  oc patch quota "my-object" -p '{"spec":{"hard":{"$OS_OBJECT":"$VALUE"}}}'
```

But that gives the error:

```
Error from server: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'
```

indicating that the variable is not substituted/expanded.

If I write it explicitly it works:

```
oc patch quota "my-object" -p '{"spec":{"hard":{"sample.k8s.io/element":"5"}}}'
```

Any suggestions on how to include a variable in the jsonstring?

**EDIT:** Based on below answer I have also tried:

```
oc patch quota "my-object" -p "{'spec':{'hard':{'$OS_OBJECT':'$VALUE'}}}"
```

but that gives the error:

```
 Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single quotes everything is preserved by bash, you have to use double quotes for string interpolation to work (and use the escape sequence \" for the other double quotes).

Try this out:

```
oc patch quota "my-object" -p "{\"spec\":{\"hard\":{\"$OS_OBJECT\":\"$VALUE\"}}}"
```

Comment: That gives: Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of object key string

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of** `OC patch` **would prefer** `OC apply` **on your templates**. **Templates are the best way to configure Openshift/Kubernetes objects** which can be stored in **git for version control to follow Infrastructure as code**.

**I am not the admin for my Openshift cluster**, so can't access the resource quotas **hence suggesting a way in Kubernetes but same can be applied in Openshift too**, except the CLI change from `kubectl` to `oc`

Let's take a **simple resource quota template**:

```
$ cat resourcequota.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: demo-quota
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: "1"
    memory: 2Gi
    pods: "10"
  scopeSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - operator : In
      scopeName: PriorityClass
      values: ["high"]
```

Now **configure your quota using** `kubectl apply` **on your template**. This creates resource which is configured in the template, in our case its `resourcequota`

```
$ kubectl apply -f resourcequota.yaml 
resourcequota/demo-quota created

$ kubectl get quota
NAME         CREATED AT
demo-quota   2019-11-19T12:23:37Z

$ kubectl describe quota demo-quota
Name:       demo-quota
Namespace:  default
Resource    Used  Hard
--------    ----  ----
cpu         0     1
memory      0     2Gi
pods        0     10
```

As your looking for an **update in resource quota using** `patch`, I would **suggest here to edit the template and execute** `kubectl apply` **again to update the object**.

```
$ kubectl apply -f resourcequota.yaml 
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
resourcequota/demo-quota configured


$ kubectl describe quota demo-quota
Name:       demo-quota
Namespace:  default
Resource    Used  Hard
--------    ----  ----
cpu         0     2
memory      0     4Gi
pods        0     20
```

Similarly, **you can execute** `oc apply` **for your operations as** `oc patch` **is not so user-friendly to configure**.

Comment: Yes I am also using versioned templates for parameterized deployments, configmaps, secrets etc. But sometime I just need a few lines in bash to patch a single line or two in existing resources.

Comment: how are those changes tracked when you do from bash? how is it applied across environments when it has to be? how do others get to know the changes applied?

Comment: I was trying to explain that tracking is not always the workflow I am in. Sometimes I  just need to update and test different configurations on live objects for experimental purposes in this case patch is perfect.

Comment: even, in that case, you will not have a backup of an older version of templates after a few days, just in case something went wrong to roll back/revert.